# Can I set a 'default center' value in react-googe-maps/api?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I was using the original `react-google-maps` package for a while but realized it hadn't been updated for a a couple years so i installed an updated package called `react-google-maps/api`. Both packages have a component called `<GoogleMap/>` but the old package had a prop you could pass to it called `defaultCenter`. Declaring this property would make it so that when the map component mounted, this value would be the center but would not change the center when the component re-rendered. This new package only seems to have a prop called `center` and the map will go back to this value whenever it re-renders. Heres the code illustrating my problem:

```
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api'

function App() {

  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button className="" onClick={() => {someState ? setSomeState(false) : setSomeState(true)}}>Click</button>
      <LoadScript
        id="script-loader"
        googleMapsApiKey=""
      >
        <GoogleMap
          id='example-map'
          mapContainerStyle={{
            height: '900px',
            width: '900px'}}
          center={{lat:41, lng: -71}}
          zoom={4}
        >
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's what happens:
1) Page loads to specified center
2) I drag the map to a different location
3) I press the button that changes the state
4) The map reloads back to the original center

how can I get the map to stay at its current location when i press the button that sets the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is to be expected. When the component `<App/>` is re-rendered, so is the `<GoogleMap/>` component inside.

You can retrieve the map instance with the `onLoad` prop and the useRef hook, so you can use the instance with `.current` property and have the center in state.

When a user drags the map (triggering `onDrag`, `onDragEnd` and `onDragStart` events) you can set the new center with the ref instance you saved.

```
function App() {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
      lat: 41, 
      lng: -71
  });

  function handleLoad(map) {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }

  function handleCenter() {
    if (!mapRef.current) return;

    const newPos = mapRef.current.getCenter().toJSON();
    setPosition(newPos);
  }

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      zoom={4}
      onLoad={handleLoad}
      onDragEnd={handleCenter}
      center={position}
      id="map"
      mapContainerStyle={{
        height: '900px',
        width: '900px'
      }}
    >
   </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! The only thing is that if  `onCenterChanged` triggers `handleCenter` it seems to cause an infinite loop. I was able to get it to work just leaving that out. However I guess this might be a problem if the center changes due to something other than a drag event.

Comment: Opsss... mistake from my side. Forgot to remove the onCenterChanged prop. Otherwise as you said it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: to prevent the infinite loop you can add the following check
`if (newPos.lat === position.lat && newPos.lng === position.lng) return` to the `handleCenter` function